# Playstation Eyetoy with Raspberry Pi

Tags: camera

i have tried to use a raspberry in order to do some time lapse recordings with an old webcam, after some research i found out it was not compatible. I have a playstation eyetoy and read it was compatible, has anyone ever used it?

Comment: As long as you are using a USB webcam, this is really a generic Linux question much more than a pi question.

Comment: This won't help with your Playstation camera, but I have used Logitech webcams with the RPi with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the raspberry pi and it's purpose-built camera module plenty of times - it works great.

You can also plug in a simple and cheap webcam to the USB port and use the opensource drivers to get a simple video feed or grab a JPG from the stream on demand with very simple code. If the Playstation Eye is not compatible with the open source video drivers for USB webcam style devices, then get one that is. The Raspberry Pi is great, and will work for your purposes, just not with that camera it seems.